# Find $x$ $\frac{(3x^2-27)(8x^2)6}{4(9-3x)(x^2+3x)}=\frac{\tan(x+4)}{\log(x \div \frac{1}{4})}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]

An easier version of my previous question. (I actually copied the question down wrong)

> Find $x$  $$\frac{(3x^2-27)(8x^2)6}{4(9-3x)(x^2+3x)}=\frac{\tan(x+4)}{\log(x \div \frac{1}{4})}$$

I'm thinking

- LHS numerator: taking the factor 3 out and expanding the right bracket
- LHS denominator: taking the factor of -3 from the left bracket and x from the right bracket

$$\frac{3(x^2-9)(6\times8x^2)}{-12x(x-3)(x+3)}=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log(x \div \frac{1}{4})} $$

$$\frac{(x^2-9)(6\times8x^2)}{-4x(x^2-9)}=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log(x \times \frac{4}{1})} \quad \text{taking the factor of 3 out and expanding noting the identity} $$

$$\frac{6\times8x^2}{-4x}=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log(4x)} \quad \text{cancelling of course, rearranging } $$
$$(-2*6x)=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log(4x)} \quad \text{even more cancelling} $$

$$(-12x)=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log(4x)}  $$

Not sure where to go from here...

Maybe....

$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{-12log(4x)}  $$

$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log(4x)^{-12}}  $$

$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log(4^{-12}x^{-12})}  $$
$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log\left(\frac{1}{4^{12}} \times \frac{1}{x^{12}} \right)}  $$
$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log\left(\frac{1}{4^{12}x^{12}}\right)} $$

$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{log\left(1\right)-log\left(4^{12}x^{12}\right)} \quad \text{$log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b)$} $$

$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{-log\left(4^{12}x^{12}\right)} \quad \text{$log(1) = 0$} $$

$$x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{-\left(log\left(4^{12}\right)+(log\left(x^{12}\right)\right)} \quad \text{$log(ab) = log(a)+log(b)$} $$

Comment: from where comes that equation?

Comment: It was a silly meme on facebook that had a poorly answered past paper. The question actually seemed interesting.

Comment: i think you must use a numerical method

Comment: I have included the meme for you Dr. Sonnhard

Comment: can you send me the other problems?

Comment: We could have gone straight from $x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{-12log(4x)}$ to $x=\frac{tan(x+4)}{-log\left(4^{12}x^{12}\right)}$.

Comment: I know i was just scribbling for answers pretty much...